# Changing color and status dynamically in angular

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, angular8

I am working on a angular application. I have a JSON response coming from rabbitmq. This response has a parameter of level and it's values can be low, medium or high. If at run time value of level comes as low then I want to represent it as shown in sample image with color in small rectangle and level written adjacent to it. [image: sample image]

For each level color should change with level name dynamically. How can I do that?

My response looks something like this

```
{
    "Source": "",
    "Type": "",
    "Timestamp": "2019-07-11T06:00:00.000Z",
    "Content": {
     level: medium
    }
}
```

I am retreiving response as follows:

```
this.subscription = this.service.subscribe(resp => {
   this.level = resp.Content.level
}
```

Comment: Hey :) can you provide us a stackblitz with an example of your problem :) ?

Comment: Can you show how response look exactly ?

Comment: @MsuArven response is as follows:  {
    "Source": "",
    "Type": "",
    "Timestamp": "2019-07-11T06:00:00.000Z",
    "Content": {
  level: medium
 }
}

Comment: @Alann sorry as of now I don't have any stackblitz but it's a normal JSON response I am getting and using subscription I am accessing contents of response

Comment: @MsuArven I  have updated code in question

Answer (score 2):

you need to create classes base of every level value like low , meduim , high..

*app.component.css*

```
.medium , .low , .high{
  margin: 1rem;
  border:1px solid currentColor;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.medium{
 color: green
}

.low {
color: yellowgreen
}

.high {
  color: red
}
```

*app.component.html*

```
<div *ngFor=" let item of items" [ngClass]="item.Content.level">
    {{item.Content.level}}
</div>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w2jp5q)

Answer (score 1):

Let's begin by setting up the example you provided but add an enum which we'll use to keep the template clean.

**some.component.ts**

```ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { of, Subscription } from 'rxjs'

// Example level enum
export enum RabbitMqResponseLevel {
  Low = 'low',
  Medium = 'medium',
  High = 'high'
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './some.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './some.component.css' ]
})
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {

  level: RabbitMqResponseLevel;
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.simulateRabbitMq.subscribe(
      (resp) => {
        this.level = resp.Content.level as RabbitMqResponseLevel; // cast the string to our enum.
      }
    )
  }

  /**
   * returns an observable that we can subscribe to for this demos purpose.
   */
  private get simulateRabbitMq() {
    return of({
      "Source": "",
      "Type": "",
      "Timestamp": "2019-07-11T06:00:00.000Z",
      "Content": {
      level: 'medium' // assuming medium is a string.
      }
    });
  }

}
```

Now we can write some styles in the components styles file that match your level string.

**some.component.css**

```css
.low { color: green; }
.medium { color: orange; }
.high { color: red; }
```

Finally your template file can stay clean and look something like this

**some.component.html**

```
Status: <span [ngClass]="level">{{level}}</span>
```

this would visually give you

[image]

Here's a stackblitz example ( I've added a delay between fake responses so you can see how the status would change as values come in )

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-changing-color-and-status-dynamically

---

> Edit: adding alternative solution for other ways of accomplishing this.

You can also separate the status color into its own component and work with the classes set in the enum more directly. This removes all the junk from the "app component" in my provided example.

In this example I create a new component that accepts a level input and sets that as the class. The rest is just to write the css to respond to the class in what ever way you would want.

In this case I've changed the font color to match the *level* as well as created a status block to match the *level* color as well.

```ts
import { Component, Input, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';
import { RabbitMqResponseLevel } from './rabbitmq-response-level.enum';

@Component({
  selector: 'level-status',
  template: `<span class="status-block"></span><ng-content></ng-content>`,
  styles: [`

    /* shape of the status block */
    :host > .status-block { 
      display: inline-block;
      width: 0.5em;
      height: 0.5em;
      margin-right: 0.5em;
      background-color: black; /* default color */
    }

    /* status block colors */
    :host.low    .status-block { background-color: green; }
    :host.medium .status-block { background-color: orange; }
    :host.high   .status-block { background-color: red; }

    /* font colors */
    :host.low     { color: green; }
    :host.medium  { color: orange; }
    :host.high    { color: red; }

  `]
})
export class LevelStatusComponent  {

  /**
   * This is the input that sets the class based on the enum string.
   * It uses HostBinding to class to auto attach the string value
   * to the elements class attribute.
   */
  @Input()
  @HostBinding('class') 
  level: RabbitMqResponseLevel;

}
```

**app.component.html**

```html
Status: <level-status [level]="level">{{level}}</level-status>
```

Here's a working live example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-changing-color-and-status-dynamically-2

Comment: I want to add color to rectangle not to text

Comment: You can change the color of the square with css rules like shown in the example I've provided. the stackblitz link shows how to do this. I'll update the post as well with an even better example of how to separate your component so its easier to manage..

Answer (score 0):

You may use ngClass https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass.

Example:

```
<your-level-element [ngClass]="{'low': parameter.level === 'low', 'medium': parameter.level === 'medium'}">
```

You will have 3 classes (one per level) with you can customize background (or any styles)

Comment: Yes, so if the value equal 'medium' only the medium class will be applied

Comment: got it but just one doubt with this 'low' I can set background color. But adjacent to rectangle I need to show text also indicating level as low, medium or high . How  I can do that?

Comment: You can use css. .low:after { content: 'Your text; otherStyles... } Otherwise you can create a dedicated component that u will use with a level Input and play with ngif

Comment: The solution isn't scalable.